# What does this part of the font tag do? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
font: 400 48px/1.2 'Oswald', sans-serif;
```

Can anyone tell me what the 48px/1.2 means? In particular the **1.2**.

What this value do and mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sets two properties and is equivalent to:

```
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 1.2;
```

The 1.2 sets a line-height value.

**Here is the complete explanation below:**

[image: Font]

Answer (score 3):

The Complete Explanation of **Font** is in the Image Below:

[image: Font]